# Android SimpleGraph issues with labeling and automatic x-axis scroll

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am working on an Android app and I have a graph of sensor readings: temp/humidity/wind plotted on Y axis, and then time/date on the X-axis. I am using the [SimpleGraph library](http://www.android-graphview.org/simple-graph/). For the most part everything works great. However, there are a 2-3 issues I've gotten stuck on.

1. If I specify a number for labels, such as 3 for my main screen, It won't scroll to the end, or which would be preferably, it doesn't just show 3 labels and all the data for the time specified. Instead it shows me the first three labels and cuts the data. If I try `graph.getViewport().scrollToEnd();` nothing changes.
2. On my 'FullGraphActivity' I am still missing the last couple of hours of data...sometimes. Othertimes, it will show.

So I know I am getting the correct data points because my logs show them. I am pretty sure they are being plotted out of view. What I'd really like is to figure out how to get the data and labels to correctly plot based on my time selection. Such as day / week / month. I've included the two main classes, and an example call for the 3 labeled call.

I'm probably missing something simple. Appreciate any suggestions, comments.

Thanks!

Call from main screen with label count specified:

```
graphTemp = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graphTemp);
            try {
                GraphUtility gu = new GraphUtility(1,1,3,true,false, this,celsius);
                gu.grapher( this,graphTemp, gu.seriesBuilder(
                        gu.getTempData(gu.getSixHours())));
```

This is where I am setting up the simple graph:

```
public class GraphUtility {
    public int focus;
    public Activity activity;
    public MainActivity mainActivity;
    public Context context;
    Constants constants;


    private final static int graphColor
    Color.parseColor("#6a0c05");
    private double maxYBound = 0;
    private double minYBound = 999;
    private int time = 0;
    private int labelCount = 0;
    private boolean maxy = true;
    private boolean miny = true;
    private boolean celsius;
    public GraphUtility(int focus, int time, int labelCount,boolean maxy, boolean miny, MainActivity mainActivity, boolean celsius) {

        this.focus = focus;
        this.time = time;
        this.labelCount = labelCount;
        context = mainActivity;
        this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
        this.miny = miny;
        this.maxy = maxy;
        this.celsius = celsius;
}



public void grapher(Context context, GraphView graph, LineGraphSeries[] seriesArray){
    try{
        graph.removeAllSeries();
        LineGraphSeries series = new LineGraphSeries();
        series.clearReference(graph);
        if(focus==0){
            for(int i = 0; i<seriesArray.length; i++){
                // series = new LineGraphSeries();
                series = seriesArray[i];
                series.setDrawBackground(true);

                if(i == 0) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
                }
                if(i == 1) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#551a8b"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#551a8b"));
                }
                if(i == 2) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0008F0"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0008F0"));
                }

                series.setDataPointsRadius(2);
                series.setThickness(2);

                graph.addSeries(series);
            }
        }
        if(focus == 1){
            series = seriesArray[0];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
        }
        if(focus == 2){
            series = seriesArray[1];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
        }
        if(focus == 3){
            series = seriesArray[2];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
        }
        series.setDataPointsRadius(2);
        series.setThickness(2);
        graph.addSeries(series);


        //graph.addSeries(series);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(graphColor);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(graphColor);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(graphColor);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.BOTH);

        graph.getViewport().scrollToEnd();
        //Add 5 percent for easier readability
        if(maxy) {
            graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
            maxYBound = maxYBound + (maxYBound* .05);
            maxYBound= 5*(Math.ceil(Math.abs(maxYBound/5)));
            if(maxYBound ==0){
                maxYBound=1;
            }

           graph.getViewport().setMaxY(maxYBound);
        }
        //Minus 5 percent
        if(minYBound !=0) {
            if(miny) {
                graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                minYBound = minYBound - (minYBound * .05);
                minYBound= 5*(Math.floor(Math.abs(minYBound/5)));
                Log.d("BTWeather-minYval", String.valueOf(minYBound));
                //TODO Empty sensors causes crash.
                graph.getViewport().setMinY(minYBound);
            }
        }

        if(labelCount > 0){
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(labelCount);
        }

        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(true);
       // graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setTextSize(35);
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().reloadStyles();
        java.text.DateFormat dateTimeFormatter = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
        if(time==1) {
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(
                    new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(graph.getContext(),
                            dateTimeFormatter));
        }else{
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(
                    new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(graph.getContext()));
        }

        //
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("BTWeather-error21", e.toString());

    }

}
// TODO Graphs not advancing again showing hours behind instead of latest sensor
public LineGraphSeries[] seriesBuilder(List<Sensors> sensorsList){
    LineGraphSeries[] seriesArray = new LineGraphSeries[3];
    try{
        DataPoint d = null;
        DataPoint[] dataPoints = new DataPoint[sensorsList.size()];
        DataPoint[] dataPointsH = new DataPoint[sensorsList.size()];
        DataPoint[] dataPointsW = new DataPoint[sensorsList.size()];
        Date date1 = new Date();
        int i = 0;
        Log.d("BTWeather-seriesbuilder",
                " Length of sensorlist: " + String.valueOf(sensorsList.size()));
        if(sensorsList.size()==0){
            minYBound = 0;
        }
        try{
            for(Sensors sensor: sensorsList){
                findMaxY(sensor);
                findMinY(sensor);
                try {

                    date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(sensor.getmDate());

                    //Log.d("BTWeather-sensorlistFG",
                    //  String.valueOf(date1)+" - " + String.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()) );
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if( isCelsius()){
                    d = new DataPoint(date1, Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()));
                }else{
                    double tmp = mainActivity.cToF(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()));

                    // Log.d("BTWeather-seriesdump",String.valueOf(tmp));
                    d = new DataPoint(date1, tmp);
                }

                dataPoints[i]= d;
                d = new DataPoint(date1, Double.valueOf(sensor.getmHumidity()));
                dataPointsH[i]=d;
                d = new DataPoint(date1, Double.valueOf(sensor.getmWind()));
                dataPointsW[i]=d;

                i++;
            }
            seriesArray[0] = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPoints);
            seriesArray[1] = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPointsH);
            seriesArray[2] = new LineGraphSeries<>(dataPointsW);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("BTWeather-error20", e.toString());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("BTWeather-error22", e.toString());
    }


    return seriesArray;
}
//TODO min / max not resetting propperly for days/weeks etc
public void findMaxY (Sensors sensor){
    try{
        //Focus passed from main activity on graph click
        if(focus ==1){
            if(  isCelsius()) {
                if (Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()) > maxYBound) {
                    maxYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp());
                }
            }else if(mainActivity.cToF(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()))>maxYBound){
                maxYBound=mainActivity.cToF(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()));
            }
        }

        else if(focus == 2){
            if( Double.valueOf(sensor.getmHumidity())> maxYBound){
                maxYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmHumidity());
            }
        }

        else if(focus == 3){
            if(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmWind())> maxYBound){
                maxYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmWind());
            }
        }}
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("BTWeather-error19", e.toString());
    }
}
public void findMinY (Sensors sensor){
    if(sensor != null) {
        try {
            //Focus passed from main activity on graph click
            if (focus == 1) {
                if (isCelsius()) {
                    if (Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()) < minYBound) {
                        minYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp());
                    }
                } else if (mainActivity.cToF(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp())) < minYBound) {
                    minYBound = mainActivity.cToF(Double.valueOf(sensor.getmTemp()));
                }
            } else if (focus == 2) {
                if (Double.valueOf(sensor.getmHumidity()) < minYBound) {
                    minYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmHumidity());
                }
            } else if (focus == 3) {
                if (Double.valueOf(sensor.getmWind()) < minYBound) {
                    minYBound = Double.valueOf(sensor.getmWind());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("BTWeather-error18", e.toString());
        }
    }else{
        minYBound=0;
    }
}

//Database
public static String getYesterday(){
    //return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000);
    long  day = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1);
    String start= DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - day)).toString();
    return start;
}
public static String getSixHours(){
    //return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000);
    long  day = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(6);
    String start= DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - day)).toString();
    return start;
}
public static String getWeek(){
    //return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000);
    long  week = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(7);
    String start= DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - week)).toString();
    return start;
}
public static String getMonth(){
    //return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-24*60*60*1000);
    long  month = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30);
    String start= DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - month)).toString();
    return start;
}
public static Date getMeTomorrow(){
    return new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
}


public List<Sensors> getTempData(String start){
    SensorsDatabase sDb = SensorsDatabase.getSensorsDatabase(context);
    List<Sensors> dataPoints = null;
    Date date1 = new Date();
    try {
        dataPoints = sDb.sensorsDao().findTempByDate(
                start,
                DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", getMeTomorrow()).toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("BTWeather-error8", String.valueOf(e));
    }
    return dataPoints;
    }

public boolean isCelsius() {
    return celsius;
}
}
```

This activity is for full view of the graph. Here it's mostly working. However, as said above, sometimes the last couple of hours worth of data is being cut off. Say its 2:30, I'll see data & labels up to 12:30

```
public class FullGraphActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
GraphView graph;
private TextView mTextMessage;
private final static int graphColor = Color.parseColor("#6a0c05");
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private int focus =0;
private int time = 0;
GraphUtility gu;
private boolean celsius;
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.graph_hour:
                time=1;
                if(focus ==1 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_hour_temp);
                if(focus ==2 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_hour_humid);
                if(focus ==3 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_hour_wind);
                try{
                    gu = new GraphUtility(focus,time,0,true,true,mainActivity,celsius);
                    gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(),graph,gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getYesterday())));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.graph_day:
                time=2;
                if(focus ==1 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_day_temp);
                if(focus ==2 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_day_humid);
                if(focus ==3 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_day_wind);
                try{
                    gu = new GraphUtility(focus,time,0,true,true,mainActivity,celsius );
                    gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(),graph,gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getWeek())));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.graph_week:
                time=3;
                if(focus ==1 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_week_temp);
                if(focus ==2 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_week_humid);
                if(focus ==3 )
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.graph_week_wind);
                try{
                    gu = new GraphUtility(focus,time,0,true,true,mainActivity,celsius );
                    gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(),graph,gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getMonth())));
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                }

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_graph);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    focus = mIntent.getIntExtra("focus", 0);
    celsius = mIntent.getBooleanExtra("celsius", false);
    mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.graphMenu);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    mainActivity = new MainActivity() ;
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
    // Setting the very 1st item as home screen.
    navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.graph_hour);



}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Hopefully this isn't too much info. Again, any comments greatly appreciated. [Full code repo if it helps.](https://github.com/JamesHarley/BTWeatherStation)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as usual, after deciding to post I was able to work out a solution with the help of the examples on simplegraphs doc. I thought I mirrored the date example from the doc but I had left out a key section:

```
// set manual x bounds to have nice steps
graph.getViewport().setMinX(start);
graph.getViewport().setMaxX(System.currentTimeMillis());
graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
```

For some reason I wasn't able to clear each graphs style/data correctly despite using the clear/resets provided in the API. Rather than waste too much time on it I decided to create three graphviews in my layout then hide the ones not in use. This isn't the best method, but it seems to not impact performance. See below for the code changes. Note some changes are made for style reasons.

I changed my  grapher method to include the double start which is the time to start from:

Class GraphUtility

```
public void grapher(Context context, GraphView graph, LineGraphSeries[] seriesArray, Double start){
    try{
        graph.removeAllSeries();

        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
        LineGraphSeries series = new LineGraphSeries();
        series.clearReference(graph);
        if(focus==0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < seriesArray.length; i++) {
                // series = new LineGraphSeries();
                series = seriesArray[i];
                series.setDrawBackground(true);

                if (i == 0) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D6a0c05"));
                }
                if (i == 1) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00004C"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D00004C"));
                }
                if (i == 2) {
                    series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
                    series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D006600"));
                }

                series.setDataPointsRadius(4);
                series.setThickness(4);
                graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(graphColor);
                graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(graphColor);
                graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(graphColor);
                graph.addSeries(series);

            }
        }
        if(focus == 1){
            series = seriesArray[0];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D6a0c05"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#8d1007"));
            series.setDataPointsRadius(2);
            series.setThickness(2);
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }
        if(focus == 2){
            series = seriesArray[1];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#00004C"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D00004C"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(Color.parseColor("#00004C"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#00004C"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#00004C"));
            series.setDataPointsRadius(2);
            series.setThickness(2);
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }
        if(focus == 3){
            series = seriesArray[2];
            series.setDrawBackground(true);
            series.setColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
            series.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4D006600"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setVerticalLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#006600"));
            series.setDataPointsRadius(2);
            series.setThickness(2);
            graph.addSeries(series);
        }


        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setGridStyle(GridLabelRenderer.GridStyle.BOTH);

        //Add 5 percent for easier readability
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,"MaxY" + String.valueOf(maxYBound));
        if(maxy) {
            graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
            maxYBound = maxYBound + (maxYBound* .05);
            maxYBound= 5*(Math.ceil(Math.abs(maxYBound/5)));
            if(maxYBound ==0){
                maxYBound=1;
            }

            graph.getViewport().setMaxY(maxYBound);
        }
        //Minus 5 percent

        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG,"MinY" + String.valueOf(minYBound));
        if(minYBound !=0) {
            if(miny) {
                graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
                minYBound = minYBound - (minYBound * .05);
                minYBound= 5*(Math.floor(Math.abs(minYBound/5)));
                Log.d("BTWeather-minYval", String.valueOf(minYBound));
                graph.getViewport().setMinY(minYBound);
            }
        }else{
            graph.getViewport().setMinY(minYBound);
        }

        if(labelCount > 0){
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(labelCount);
        }
        if(time==1) {
            java.text.DateFormat dateTimeFormatter = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(
                    new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(graph.getContext(),
                            dateTimeFormatter));
        }else{
            graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(context));
        }

        //graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setNumHorizontalLabels(labelCount); // only 4 because of the space

        // set manual x bounds to have nice steps
        graph.getViewport().setMinX(start);
        graph.getViewport().setMaxX(System.currentTimeMillis());
        graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);

        // as we use dates as labels, the human rounding to nice readable numbers
        // is not necessary
        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHumanRounding(false);
        //graph.getGridLabelRenderer().reloadStyles();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("BTWeather-error21", e.toString());

    }
}
```

Class FullGraphActivity: Only changes needed were for the grapher call and for hiding/showing the correct view depending on the time call.

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.graph_hour:
                time=1;
                if(focus==0) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.AllHourly);

                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 6, true, true, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getYesterday())),gu.getYesterdayDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }else {
                    if (focus == 1)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_hour_temp);
                    if (focus == 2)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_hour_humid);
                    if (focus == 3)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_hour_wind);
                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
                        graph.removeAllSeries();
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 6, true, true, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getYesterday())),gu.getYesterdayDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.graph_day:
                time=2;
                if(focus==0){
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.AllDaily);
                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
                        graph.removeAllSeries();
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 7, true, true, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getWeek())),gu.getWeekDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }else {
                    if (focus == 1)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_day_temp);
                    if (focus == 2)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_day_humid);
                    if (focus == 3)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_day_wind);
                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
                        graph.removeAllSeries();
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 7, true, true, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getWeek())),gu.getWeekDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.graph_week:
                time=3;
                if(focus==0){
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.AllWeekly);
                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
                        graph.removeAllSeries();
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 8, false, false, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getMonth())),gu.getMonthDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }else {
                    if (focus == 1)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_week_temp);
                    if (focus == 2)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_week_humid);
                    if (focus == 3)
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.graph_week_wind);
                    try {
                        GraphView graph2;
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        graph2 = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph2);
                        graph2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        GraphView graph;
                        graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.fullGraph3);
                        graph.getGridLabelRenderer().resetStyles();
                        graph.removeAllSeries();
                        graph.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        gu = new GraphUtility(focus, time, 8, true, true, mainActivity, celsius);
                        gu.grapher(getApplicationContext(), graph, gu.seriesBuilder(gu.getTempData(gu.getMonth())),gu.getMonthDouble());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d("BTWeather-error15", e.toString());
                    }
                }

                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

If I find a solution to the multiple views I'll edit this post in case it's useful for someone in the future.

Best,
James